# Input size of neural net doesn't match

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to machine learning and trying to build CNN for mnist fashion dataset and there's some error in this program that says

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

I've tried many solutions but none of them actually worked.

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = mnist_fashion.load_data()
mnist_fashion = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
x_train,x_test = x_train/255,x_test/255

model = Sequential([

    Conv2D(64,(4,4),activation='relu',input_shape = (28,28,1), padding='same'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    Dropout(0.1),

    Conv2D(64,(4,4),activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    Dropout(0.3),

    Flatten(),

    Dense(256,activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),

    Dense(64,activation='relu'),

    Dense(10,activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape your data from `(60000, 28, 28)` to `(60000, 28, 28, 1)`:

```py
x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1), np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
```

You probably also want to feed one-hot encoded labels. To transform to one-hot encoded labels do this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(n_values=10)
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(np.expand_dims(y_train, -1))
y_test = encoder.transform(np.expand_dims(y_test, -1))
```